# PHP-EWS How to get unique ID of mail

Tags: php

I am using the https://github.com/jamesiarmes/php-ews library to get *mail* from *exchange online*. But I can not get the **unique ID** of the *mail*. I can only get *ItemId* as follows:

```
 AAMkADFmZWE1Y2EyLTEwNGUtNDk3Zi04YzFiLWRiZDcxYjdhMjU5NwBGAAAAAAA8Kc 
 / jYLLhQaPH3pShvf8nO / AAAM47UjAAA =
```

Thanks for help.

Comment: isnt the itemID the unique emailId ?

Comment: I want it to be an ID in integer form. So how can I get it?

Comment: the id you provided looks valid, thats the id of an item in an exchange account and this id you can use to act with the item using php-ews